# How to initialize the datastore with a default entity in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Let say I have a particular model

```
class Page(db.Model):
    """ Model for storing wiki pages """
    page_name = db.StringProperty(required=True, default="/")
    content = db.StringProperty(required=True, default="")
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

What I want to do is query the data store. If there are no entities based on this model I want to create a default entity. Alternatively created the model with one default entity would be great.

I am aware of the **init** method in Python which is used to set initial values to attributes, but when I use this with the GAE & webapp2 within a Get method of a request handler I get an error.

The code that errors is:

```
class WikiPage(Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The error I see is:

```
handler = self.handler(request, response)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Please advise

Comment: Your handler inherits from webapp2. Look in the webapp2 docs here: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-init

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do but if you simply want to rid of the error you need to define the `__init__` method like this:

```
class WikiPage(Handler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

**UPDATE** to answer your question "**why**":

Because you are overriding the `__init__` method of the `Handler` class which inherits from `RequestHandler` and if you take a look at its original definition here: https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#506 you'll see that that's how it is defined and that's how it is used throughout the framework which means if you for any reason decide to override it, you need to follow the same format.

Comment: Can you please explain why it need to be like this?

Comment: Yes I did see this definition but assumed that since the other two parameters have default values that they were taken care of. I will test and let you know. Peace to you

Comment: @ImranNazir, yes, the original definition has default values, you can define them too if you'd like. You are overriding (completely replacing) the original definition (since you don't seem to be calling `super`) so whatever was defined there does not play any role any more. The issue is that some other code (incoming request handler) is passing **3** parameters to the `__init__` method, but your implementation of `__init__` method only accepts **one** (self) which is the reason your code failed.

Comment: Yes I understand that the routes can pass in parameters to the handlers. I use them this way in my get methods. My route in this case is: '(PAGE_RE, WikiPage)' where 'PAGE_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)'' this should pass into the get method of my handler everything that comes after baseurl. This would be 1 parameter passed, not 3